# using getter setter variables within a loop

Tags: java, for-loop, getter-setter

Is there a way to use getter method as a variable, I mean in here i want to replace *getDiscountCode()* with a variable

```
for (int row=0; row < pOSBean.getItemList().size(); row++) {
   valueDTO = new ValueDTO();
   valueDTO.setRowId(1);
   valueDTO.setValue(pOSBean.getItemList().get(row).getDiscountCode());
   valueListDTO.add(valueDTO);
}
```

something like this

```
variable = getDiscountCode();

for (int row=0; row < pOSBean.getItemList().size(); row++) {
   valueDTO = new ValueDTO();
   valueDTO.setRowId(1);
   valueDTO.setValue(pOSBean.getItemList().get(row).+variable);
   valueListDTO.add(valueDTO);
}
```

i can't use *'pOSBean.getItemList().get(row).getDiscountCode()'* row as a variable cuz rowid is there
any Suggestions plz

```
public List<ItemCartDTO> getItemList() {
    return itemList;
}

public class ItemCartDTO implements Serializable {
    private String locCode;
    private List<CommonDropdownItemsDTO> selectedItmStockList;
    private String discountCode;

    public String getDiscountCode() {
        return discountCode;
    }
    public void setDiscountCode(String discountCode) {
        this.discountCode = discountCode;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functional interface [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) for that purpose:

```
Function<Integer, DISCOUNT_CODE> method = (row) -> pOSBean.getItemList().get(row).getDiscountCode(); // Edit DISCOUNT_CODE Type
```

The Function will take a Integer (your row) and return the discount code:

```
valueDTO.setValue(method.apply(row));
```

You may also look into the [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes). With that type of loop you can make your loop even prettier:

```
for (Item item : pOSBean.getItemList())
{
    valueDTO = new ValueDTO();
    valueDTO.setRowId(1);
    valueDTO.setValue(item.getDiscountCode());
    valueListDTO.add(valueDTO);
}
```

Comment: Learned a new thing thanks to u rollback. Great! it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

There are some important details missing.  For example, when you call `valueDTO.setValue(...)`, what type does `setValue` expect?  Any `Object`?  A `String`?  Some custom class?  If it's a custom class, are there really multiple getters that you could vary between, that would return that class?

Say `setValue`'s parameter is an `Object`.  If `getRow()` returns something of class `YourClass`, you can write:

```
Function<YourClass, Object> getter = YourClass::getDiscountCode;
```

and call it like this:

```
valueDTO.setValue(getter.apply(pOSBean.getItemList().get(row)));
```

Comment: Thnks ajb. It worked!! and i added the missing details.